# Geom_bar with R (Beginner)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry

Good morning all,

I work on data that I would like to represent in the form of a bar graph by two according to my two departments. I generated a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> test = data.frame (type_transport = sample (c ("ON FOOT", "CAR", "TRANSPORT COMMON"), 5000, replace = T), type_route = sample (c ("N", "D", " A "," VC "), 5000, replace = T), department = sample (c (" department1"," department2"), 5000, replace = T), troncon = sample (x = 0: 17 , 5000, replace = T))
```

By entering this formula, I get a bar graph:

```
> ggplot (test, aes (x = route_type, y = troncon_km, fill = department)) + geom_bar (stat = "identity")
```

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/19/vt1s.png

Now, I would like to split these bars in half, to display the data according to my two departments. For this, I use position = "dodge":

```
> ggplot (test, aes (x = road_type, y = troncon_km, fill = department)) + geom_bar (stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

But there is a problem. The Y scale is far too small compared to reality (we go from several thousand on the first graph to 15 on the second). I obviously missed something ...

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/19/sbh5.png

I do not understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is `y=troncon` used in the first plot but `y = troncon_km length` in the second plot. Are the same values stores in both?

Comment: Oups ! Little mistake, it's corrected. My problem remains the same despite this correction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why all bars are of equal height is because `geom_bar(stat="identity")` will plot a bar for each observation (and the height of the bar will equal the value for that observation). Since every category in both departments have at least 1 observation of 17, all bars are showing that value.

There are several ways to move forward:

  1.

```
ggplot(test, aes(type_route, troncon_km, fill = department)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", position = "dodge", fun.y = sum)
```

The fun.y argument can be any other function (e.g. mean, or median etc.)

2.

```
library("tidyverse")
total_km <- test %>%
    group_by(department, type_route) %>%
    summarise(total_km = sum(troncon_km)) 

ggplot(total_km, aes(type_route, total_km, fill = department)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Again you can change the `sum()` function within the `summarise()` to your liking.

3. using the same data frame `total_km`, only a litle bit shorter using `geom_col`

```
ggplot(total_km, aes(type_route, total_km, fill = department)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A huge thank you to you. It also helps me to progress :)